# How get "miscStatus" from vb6 ocx?

Tags: .net, vb6, regfreecom, reg-free

How I can get **miscStatus** for VB6 ocx from .net without need for register it on local computer?

I use **TLI** (TypeLibInfo) for all other info about ocx but this property i do not know how get?

Did someone know how regsvr32 generate MiscStatus when register ocx?

---

EDIT: I forget say that I want obtain `miscStatus` from ocx without need for register it on local computer.

Comment: AFAIK regsvr32 will call a function in the OCX / DLL called DLLRegisterServer. That's all. That function itself has all the knowledge about what to register.

Answer (score 0):

You can try locating the OCX in the Registry using `Registry.GetValue`. It sounds like you probably already have the OCX's CLSID:

```
Dim ocxClsid As String = "13DE4A42-8D21-4C8E-BF9C-8F69CB068FCA" ' Replace with your CLSID
Dim key As String = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{" & ocxClsid & "}\"

Dim readValue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
    key, "MiscStatus", Nothing)
```

Comment: I forget say that I want obtain miscStatus from ocx without need for register it on local computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a standard tool like TLI that can do this. `miscStatus` appears to be written during registration by the `DLLRegisterFunction` call, which is provided by the DLL/OCX itself and can do basically anything it wants.

For instance, the registry values to be written during registration might be [contained in a resource](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/search?q=FireTabCtrl.rgs&unscoped_q=FireTabCtrl.rgs). But that is up to the programmer.

Looking at [some older source code](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/blob/master/VC2010Samples/MFC/controls/regsvr/regsvr.cpp) of regsvr32 itself you can see it totally omits the keyword `miscstatus`. I think this confirms that its value isn't required to be stored in any standardized way.

If you absolutely cannot register the OCX on your dev/build PC, the next best thing I can think of would be to register it in some kind of sandbox - like a VM, or [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/), or maybe even Docker. Then you can throw away the sandbox after reading the registry value. But I've never really tried this.

---

Also, consider if that value really is essential. If you leave it out, does anything break? It may be that many of [the misc status flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/ne-oleidl-olemisc) are not set or don't matter for your particular applicaiton.